# 'brownie' is not recognized as an internal or external command on Windows 10

Tags: windows, brownie, installation

I downloaded eth brownie via

```
pipx install eth-brownie
```

and got

```
'eth-brownie' already seems to be installed. Not modifying existing installation in 'C:\\Users\\HP\\.local\\pipx\\venvs\\eth-brownie'. Pass '--force' to force installation.
```

when I type Brownie for confirmation I get

```
'brownie' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

tried to do

```
C:\\Users\\HP\\.local\\pipx\\venvs\\eth-brownie --force
```

but got

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Edit: I tried installing and reinstalling all versions of python and tried to install brownie by using

```
pip install eth-brownie
```

but it says

```
C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
```

I'm on windows if that makes any difference any help would be amazing thx

Comment: Started a bounty.

Comment: I think this is pipx related issue. could you instead install browie into a venv ? => https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#other-installation-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the same problem while running brownie. The following are the steps that helped me fix the error.

1. First, I have uninstalled pipx and removed pipx directory from C:\Users\{Your
   user_name}\.local\ in which even the eth-brownie folder is located.
2. Uninstalled Python and again reinstalled it, but this time with the custom
   install
   option as shown in the below image. Make sure you check the first option "**Install
   for all users**"

[image]

3. Now just to make sure, check for python --version & pip --version. If everything
   is fine. Great!! Else please check if the respective PATHs are added to environment
   variables.
4. Now install pipx using pip through following commands.

   - python -m pip install --user pipx
   - python -m pipx ensurepath
5. Now make sure that pipx executable (pipx.exe) is added to the PATH in
   environment variables. In my case "C:\Users{Your
   user_name}\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts" which is generally where you
   will find it.
6. Also make sure "c:\users{Your user_name}.local\bin" is added to the PATH,
   which by default gets added during pipx installation.
7. Now try pipx --version which hopefully should give something like "1.1.0".
8. Now install brownie using "pipx install eth-brownie"
9. To check if everything worked, type "brownie" in the command prompt, which
   hopefully should give something like
   "Brownie v1.19.0 - Python development framework for Ethereum"

This would hopefully solve both pipx and brownie errors. Please let me know if
this was helpful. Thank You!!

Comment: This actually worked thx so much!

Comment: My pleasure !! @AngelDev

Answer (score 4):

I faced this problem today installing brownie on friend's machine.

**Problem:**
Was with Pipx paths used for installing/accessing brownie & python.

For some reason, even uninstalling and re-installing pipx did not change the python version/paths being used by it. Eg. We uninstalled v3.10, installed v3.9, reinstalled pipx. Pipx would still go looking for Python310.

**What worked for us:**

1. We uninstalled pipx and brownie through "pip uninstall", removed all versions of Pythons we had installed (3.6, 3.9, 3.10)
2. Reinstalled v3.9 along with system path and for all users
3. In Control Panel, "Edit System Environment Variables", removed all non-needed python version paths
4. Now in cmd, I would get the correct version with "python --version", however was still getting an error with "python3 --version"
5. In the C:\Python39 directory, create a copy of python.exe and rename to python3.exe - this would stop any error with using "python3"
6. Installed brownie using

   ```
    pip install eth-brownie
   ```

Brownie worked just fine after that. Pipx is still giving a hard time though.

Comment: Any chance you have a way to solve this with `pipx`?

Comment: Nopes. Unable to install with 'pipx' :(

Comment: I'd rather see the pipx solution to this.. Any chance you can solve how to install pipx and add that as an answer here too?

Comment: Tried this and now it shows  fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory